# cant access hdfs through java code

Tags: java, hadoop

I just want to access Hadoop file system through a Java code but I constantly seem to get exception

```
public class hdfsClient {

public hdfsClient() {}

public void addFile(String source, String dest) throws IOException{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
    conf.addResource(new Path("/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));
    FileSystem fs = null;
    try {
        fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in getting the fileSystem");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now the main file is something like this

```
public class testMain {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    hdfsClient client = new hdfsClient();

    if (args[0].equals("add")) {
        if (args.length < 3) {
            System.out.println("Usage: hdfsclient add <local_path> " +
            "<hdfs_path>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        client.addFile(args[1], args[2]);
    }
}

}
```

I created these files in eclipse and exported as JAR and then i use

```
java -jar <jarname> add <path in local system> <path in hadoop>
```

The exact command is

```
java -jar add.jar add /home/aman/test.txt /
```

I get the following error

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 cannot communicate with client version 4
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.checkVersion(RPC.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createNamenode(DFSClient.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1446)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1464)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:124)
at crud.crud.hdfsClient.addFile(hdfsClient.java:28)
at crud.crud.testMain.main(testMain.java:16)
```

Any help i tried for two whole days but couldnt resolve the problem any help

PS :
Output fromm `jps`

```
16341 Jps
14985 NameNode
20704 -- process information unavailable
15655 NodeManager
15146 DataNode
15349 SecondaryNameNode
15517 ResourceManager
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634985/error-when-trying-to-write-to-hdfs-server-ipc-version-9-cannot-communicate-with and the fifth post in http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/server-ipc-version-9/. It sounds like you have a library conflict.

Comment: You should see this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453336/exception-in-thread-main-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-remoteexception-server-ipc-ver/31483536#31483536

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i used hadoop core dependency in the pom.xml file, and hadoop core was a part of hadoop 1.X package and the rest of the dependency was from hadoop 2.X hence there was a version conflict. Removing the hadoop core dependency solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the version mismatch in the libraries that you used in the code. Remove all the libraries and add the corresponding libraries collected from your hadoop installation itself.