# importing avro data using java api in sqoop

Tags: bigdata, sqoop

The problem is how to run java program for sqoop import ?

I am using sqoop version 1.4.7 and hadoop version 2.7.2 and I 
         am trying to run on net beans ide 8.1
         here is the code:

```
 package sqoop5;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.util.Properties;
 import com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions;
 import com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.BaseSqoopTool;
 import com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;

 public class Sqoop5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
      String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
      Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
      SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();
      options.setConnectString(("jdbc:postgresql://
      127.0.0.1:5432/postgres"));
      options.setTableName(("new"));
      options.setUsername(("postgres"));
      options.setPassword(("********"));
      options.setNumMappers(1);
      options.setTargetDir(("hdfs://  
      127.0.0.1:9000/usr/new11"));     
      options.setFileLayout(com.cloudera.sqoop.
      SqoopOptions.FileLayout.AvroD ataFile);
      new ImportTool().run((com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions) 
      options);
    }    
 }
```

The error message is as follows:

```
cause:org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC 
         version 9 
         cannot communicate with client version 4
         Aug 05, 2019 10:46:29 AM org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool run
         SEVERE: Encountered IOException running import job: 
         org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: Server IPC version 9 
         cannot 
         communicate with client version 4
         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1113)
         at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453336/exception-in-thread-main-org-apache-hadoop-ipc-remoteexception-server-ipc-ver) post, you will see that it's something similar to your problem. 
Probably a version mismatch between the applications. Check the version of hadoop  you are including vs the version of hadoop from your cluster.